# insert throws invalid column index

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I have an oracle database with following scheme:

- DM_ID, auto numbering PK
- t_ID, varchar
- Workflow, varchar
- Technology, varchar
- Name_event, varchar
- Time_event, date

I use following method to make some inserts in the database.

```
private void insert(String folder, int seconds) throws SQLException {
          stm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DM_PROCMON (DM_ID,t_ID, WORKFLOW, TECHNOLOGY, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT) VALUES(DM_ID.nextval,'?', 'up', 'Folder','?', ?)");
            stm.setString(1, String.format("%d%d%d.txt",random.nextInt(999),random.nextInt(999),random.nextInt(999)));
            stm.setString(2, folder);
            stm.setTime(3, new Time(seconds * 1000));
            stm.execute();
        }
```

What I get is an SQL exception which says:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

When I debug, I see it's on the line:

> stm.setString(2, folder);

I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the apex around the ?

```
stm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DM_PROCMON (DM_ID,t_ID, WORKFLOW, TECHNOLOGY, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT) VALUES(DM_ID.nextval,?, 'up', 'Folder',?, ?)");
```

and try again.

is the method `setString` of `PreparedStatement` that handle the apex around any string for you.